# Python: Counting words from a given file starting with 'L'

Tags: list

I am new to python.I want to know how to count the number of words **starting with a particular letter say 'L'** from a text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting words starting with a character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585830/counting-words-starting-with-a-character)

Answer (score 1):

[str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Give this a shot but import your file there are also a few other ways.

```
list = ["apple", "bannana", "custard", "shoe", "ant", "police", "python"]
newList = []

for word in list:
    if word.startswith('a'):
        newList.append(word)

print newList
['apple', 'ant']
```